# Properties provided by GCM

Tags: authentication, gcm, integrity

In the introduction of NIST Special Publication 800-38D is said that:

> GCM provides assurance of the confidentiality of data using a variation of the Counter mode of operation  for  encryption. GCM  provides  assurance  of  the  authenticity  of  the  confidential  data  (up to about 64 gigabytes per invocation) using a universal hash function that is defined over a binary  Galois  (i.e.,  finite)  field.    GCM  can  also  provide  authentication  assurance  for  additional data (of practically unlimited length per invocation) that is not encrypted.

As a block cipher GCM guarantees the confidentiality of data, but what does it mean that it assures its authenticity?
And what is exactly the authentication assurance for the unencrypted additional data?

I believe that data authenticity may correspond to its integrity, i.e. the absence of tamperings, while I'm not sure of the meaning of the authentication for the additional data.

Comment: GCM is essentially combining a [Message authentication code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) (to ensure integrity of message and additional data) and encryption (to ensure confidentiality of the message)

Comment: So the authentication of the additional data corresponds only to the property that it is received in the same condition that it was sent out, without modifications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Authenticity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication) of the data assures that the data in question was created or modified by an authorized party (a key holder). Without authenticity, anyone could present an arbitrary block of data as a valid ciphertext. Though it is overwhelmingly likely that decrypting such a block will result in a garbage plaintext, it can still disrupt the application that is attempting to use the data. This is different from [integrity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_integrity), in that integrity assures you that a given piece of data has not been modified (either by an unauthorized party or by more mundane sources of data corruption such as bad hardware/line noise/cosmic rays/etc).

> So the authentication of the additional data corresponds only to the property that it is received in the same condition that it was sent out, without modifications?

Technically, integrity is what guarantees that the data was received in the same condition as it was sent out. Authenticity assures that the data originated from an authorized party.

Integrity can be seen as a subset of Authenticity. For example, you can obtain integrity by hashing a message. This does not provide authenticity though. For that, you require a [MAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836100/what-is-the-difference-between-a-hash-and-mac-message-authentication-code).

Comment: And the MAC corresponds to the tag provided by GCM in this case, am I right?

Comment: @M-elman Yes, the "tag" produced by GCM is a message authentication code.

Comment: However, that's doesn't provide a signature (and so the non-repudiation) of the message, for which I need an asymmetric cryptographic scheme, if I'm not wrong.

Comment: @M-elman I do not know your use case, but a MAC can be created/validated by anyone who holds the secret key; A digital signature allows any number of parties to verify authenticity/integrity, without giving them the ability to create authentic messages.

Comment: There's a weakness in this answer, which is that it fails to address one easy misunderstanding: the concept of *associated data* in authenticated encryption does not require that the associated data be communicated through the channel, only that both the encryptor and decryptor agree on the associated data for each message. Associated data is often *contextual* rather than part of the cryptogram; for example, an application could use the authentication tags of previous messages as associated data for later ones to protect against attackers who delete or reorder otherwise authentic messages.

Comment: @LuisCasillas I understand what you are saying, but is that really on topic to include in this answer? Where the additional data comes from and what it is used for doesn't appear to be related to the question, unless there is some part of it that I am not seeing. The questioner appeared to need some definitions of integrity/authenticity sorted out, and there is no mention of how any data is transferred or when or what it is used for. I did not address such things because the question did not ask about them.

Comment: @LuisCasillas My problem was in the understanding the meanings of authenticity and integrity. Anyway I appreciate your comment and I found it useful. I will keep in mind that associated data doesn't need to be sent through the channel. I take this opportunity to ask instead whether it CAN be sent in clear through the channel.

Comment: @EllaRose: My concern is that when I was introduced to the concept of associated data I failed to fully grasp its value because too many introductory explanations assume that this data is transmitted along with the ciphertext.